# mysql select where limit, join where

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have following two MySQL tables

- products (product_id, name, category)
- products_sizes (product_id, size)

every product can have multiple sizes

I need to make a query that

1. selects a product based on category and size (if size is set) - e.g. category = 'shoes' and size = '10'
2. it must still return all sizes for the product, but only if the product has the specific size as on of its sizes
3. it must at the same time limit the results of products to a certain number with an offset

What I have now the query below. I works but doesn't constrain by category and only returns the one size specified (here '10') - I need all sizes, but only for the products that have '10' among its sizes...

```
SELECT products.*
     , products_sizes.*
FROM (
   SELECT *
   FROM products 
   LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset
   ) AS products
LEFT JOIN products_sizes 
   ON products.products_id = products_sizes.products_id 
WHERE products_sizes.size = 10
```

... and if I add WHERE category = 'something' query returns nothing...

```
SELECT products.*
     , products_sizes.*
FROM (
   SELECT * 
   FROM products 
   WHERE category = 'shoes' 
   LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset
   ) AS products
LEFT JOIN products_sizes 
   ON products.products_id = products_sizes.products_id
WHERE products_sizes.size = 10
```

??

**UPDATE: getting closer...**

After reading the answers I now have this:

```
SELECT *
FROM products AS p 
LEFT JOIN products_sizes AS s 
    ON p.product_id = s.product_id
    WHERE s.product_id 
        IN (SELECT product_id FROM s WHERE size = 10)
    AND p.category = 'shoes'
```

It satisfies my initial question's first two requirements:

1. Returns results constrained by category and size
2. Returns all sizes for each product if one of its sizes equals the specified size

... BUT I still need to limit the results to a certain number of products. If I put a LIMIT $limit at the very end of the query, it will limit the number of sizes returned and not the number of products... Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

The `WHERE` clause in your main query is defeating the purpose of your `LEFT JOIN`, making it the same as an `INNER JOIN`.  It's very possible that there are not any rows selected by your derived table that match (shoes of size 10).

Unless there is something about your data not shown, you can try this:

```
SELECT products.*
     , products_sizes.*
FROM products 
JOIN products_sizes 
   ON products.products_id = products_sizes.products_id
WHERE products.category = 'shoes' 
   AND products_sizes.size = 10
LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset
```

Answer (score 0):

Your final query was absolutely correct. Just use the limit inside the subquery, that'll bind the number of products.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't use `LIMIT` in an IN-subquery

Answer (score 0):

There are at least three result formats that you might want:

1. One row per size but limited to 10 distinct products
2. 10 rows - one per product with a column containing comma separated sizes
3. Two result sets, which will be combined in PHP:

   - 10 products
   - related sizes

For every format you need somehow to return 10 distinct products matching your conditions.

The most expressive way is to use an EXISTS statement:

```
select p.*
from products p
where p.category = 'shoes'
and exists (
    select *
    from products_sizes ps
    where ps.product_id = p.product_id
      and ps.size = 10
)
order by p.product_id
limit $limit offset $offset
```

Another way is to use a JOIN:

```
select p.*
from products p
join products_sizes ps
  on ps.product_id = p.product_id
where p.category = 'shoes'
  and ps.size = 10
order by p.product_id
limit $limit offset $offset
```

I will farther use the second one because of its compact code. But you can always replace it with the EXISTS statement.

**1.**

```
select p.*, ps.size
from (
    select p.*
    from products p
    join products_sizes ps
      on ps.product_id = p.product_id
    where p.category = 'shoes'
      and ps.size = 10
    order by p.product_id
    limit $limit offset $offset
) p
join products_sizes ps
  on ps.product_id = p.product_id
order by p.product_id, ps.size
```

**2.**

```
select p.*, group_concat(ps.size order by ps.size) as sizes
from products p
join products_sizes ps1
  on ps1.product_id = p.product_id
join products_sizes ps
  on ps.product_id = p.product_id
where p.category = 'shoes'
  and ps1.size = 10
group by p.product_id
order by p.product_id
limit $limit offset $offset
```

You can use `explode()` to convert the string to an array in PHP:

```
$product->sizes = explode(',' $product->sizes);
```

**3.**

```
select p.*
from products p
join products_sizes ps
  on ps.product_id = p.product_id
where p.category = 'shoes'
  and ps.size = 10
limit $limit offset $offset
```

Store the result in an array indexed by product id. E.g. in the fetchAssoc-loop:

```
$row->sizes = array();
$products[$row->product_id] = $row;
```

Extract the product IDs from the result:

```
$productIds = (',', array_keys($products));
```

Fetch the related sizes with;

```
select product_id, size
from products_sizes
where product_id in ($productIds)
order by product_id, size
```

Link the sizes in a loop

```
$products[$row->product_id]->sizes[] = $row->size;
```

Given the following sample data

```
| product_id |   name | category | sizes |
|------------|--------|----------|-------|
|          1 | shoes1 |    shoes |   8,9 |
|          2 | shirt1 |   shirts | 10,11 |
|          3 | shoes2 |    shoes |  9,10 |
|          4 | shoes3 |    shoes | 10,11 |
|          5 | shoes4 |    shoes | 10,12 |
```

and using `LIMIT 2 OFFSET 0`, the results will be:

**1.**

```
| product_id |   name | category | size |
|------------|--------|----------|------|
|          3 | shoes2 |    shoes |    9 |
|          3 | shoes2 |    shoes |   10 |
|          4 | shoes3 |    shoes |   10 |
|          4 | shoes3 |    shoes |   11 |
```

**2.**

```
| product_id |   name | category | sizes |
|------------|--------|----------|-------|
|          3 | shoes2 |    shoes |  9,10 |
|          4 | shoes3 |    shoes | 10,11 |
```

**3.**

```
| product_id |   name | category |
|------------|--------|----------|
|          3 | shoes2 |    shoes |
|          4 | shoes3 |    shoes |

| product_id | size |
|------------|------|
|          3 |    9 |
|          3 |   10 |
|          4 |   10 |
|          4 |   11 |
```

Demos:

- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/903c1/6
- http://rextester.com/RZW84326

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *
FROM products AS p
LEFT JOIN products_sizes AS s ON p.product_id = s.product_id
WHERE p.product_id IN (SELECT product_id FROM products_sizes WHERE size = 10)
LIMIT 15
```

**EDIT (explanation):**

I was thinking about it and realized you might want to know the reasoning too :p

You are interested in the *products* that meet a certain criteria, so that's your primary table to select from.

You'd like to know the sizes available for that product, join sizes to products.

You are only interested in the products that have a certain size. Run a sub-query to find which products have that size. Display only those products.

Comment: this gives me a "Subquery returns more than 1 row" error and seems to limit the number of sizes returned, not the number of products. Please see the update to the question. I'm not quite there yet, but used your input from this answer. Thanks

Comment: @AndreasBloch I just took a look at you update. Try using the LIMIT inside the sub-query. That should limit the number of product_ids that you match against.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work. I was thinking the where clause needed to go in the second line of the query (intuitively makes most sense to me) so it would say `FROM products LIMIT $limit AS p` - but that also gives me an error

Comment: Sullivan...you used '=' instead of 'in' while your subquery is returning more than one row.